# What are hardware requirements to run Hyperledger Fabric peer?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

What are minimum hardware requirements to run a Hyperledger Fabric v1 peer?

Answer (score 9):

It can run on a RaspberryPi, so technically it does not need much if you aren't planning on doing much with it. However, to achieve the performance results you might expect, you'll need to look to achieving the right balance of network, processor, disk and CPU speeds. Additionally, as the peer is essentially managing a database, you'll need to take into consideration the data storage needs over time.

You'll also need to consider such factors as number of chaincode smart contracts, the number of expected channels and the size of the network. IOW, the hardware requirements will really depend on many other factors than simply what the peer (or orderer) process requires to minimally function.

If you are merely interested in running a development/test cluster of 4 peer nodes, an orderer and CA, keep in mind that this can all be easily handled on a Macbook Pro with 16G memory, and with slightly less ease at 8G memory. You can use that as a yardstick for cloud instances to run a development/test cluster.

Finally, there's a LOT of crypto processing, so you will want to consider hardware crypto acceleration to yield the optimal performance.

Comment: So if setting up a network with each peer on its own server, 4G per server should be enough, or should it be better to use 8G for a production environment?  Also then, if we don't have hardware acceleration, better to use a stronger processor, do you suggest anything? 4 cores?